# Can I use Chef-Solo to provision a server created with knife-eucalyptus

Tags: chef, chef-solo, knife, eucalyptus

I am able to create a new server using knife-eucalyptus like so:

```
knife euca server create
```

The server gets created but provisioning fails with the following message:

```
"ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /etc/chef/validation.pem"
```

This is understandable as I presume it is trying to use Chef Server for provisioning. This is the problem. I want to use Chef Solo to provision this server (at least for now).

Is there some way to instruct knife-eucalyptus to provision new servers with Chef Solo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [knife-solo](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/). As knife-eucalyptus uses the standard `Knife::Bootstrap` class which knife-solo monkey patches a bit, you can put `knife[:solo] = true` into the *knife.rb*.

Consult the documentation for information how to set up the "kitchen" if you're not familiar with knife-solo yet.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in my question but I _am_ using Chef Solo to provision. The thing is that `knife euca server create` creates my server at my EC2 provicer but then fails as mentioned. At that point I have to log into the server, add my SSH key, run `knife solo prepare root@servername.com` and then run `knife solo cook root@servername.com my_client_definition_file.json`. What I actually wanted to ask was how to combine all those steps into one (or maybe two... at least I want to avoid having to log in and add the SSH keys).

Comment: Ahh... nevermind. I'm an idiot. I just tried your solution and it "works". Only thing is that I should be using some provisioning keypair instead of creating a server with the default keypair.
So in short your answer works just fine.